# Azure kubernates : connect VM residing in another subnet to container

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

So I have deployed a container containing a microservice in Azure Kubernetes cluster in subnet A. And I have another microservice that is running on a VM but in another subnet B. I have to call rest APIs of the application running inside the container from a VM. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to achieve that is by creating an [internal load balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb).

From the docs:

> To restrict access to your applications in Azure Kubernetes Service
> (AKS), you can create and use an internal load balancer. An internal
> load balancer makes a Kubernetes service accessible only to
> applications running in the same virtual network as the Kubernetes
> cluster.

Follow [Specify a different subnet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb#specify-a-different-subnet) section:

> To specify a subnet for your load balancer, add the
> azure-load-balancer-internal-subnet annotation to your service. The
> subnet specified must be in the same virtual network as your AKS
> cluster. When deployed, the load balancer EXTERNAL-IP address is part
> of the specified subnet.

**Example:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: internal-app
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal-subnet: "apps-subnet"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: internal-app
```

**Diagram:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How can I set DNS, so that I don't have to worry about the IP change?

Comment: You don't specify any hard-coded IP, you just need to pass the name of the subnet under `service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal-subnet`

Comment: I am asking about DNS for container IP, so that whenever I curl API from VM to container , I can use same dns name in url

Comment: I suggest you open a new question regarding this issue since it's hard to understand via comments.